# Error Resetting mysql password

Tags: mysql, windows

I have MySQL 5.6 installed using installer. I have forgotten my password. So I have followed some method to reset the root password for root. The command I gave was this:

```
2014-04-26 11:28:45 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprec
ted. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentat
on for more details).
```

The command prompt silently returns without starting Mysql. I need to actually reset the password.  i don't know what is the problem

This is command i've used

```
C:\Users\Breeze> "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin\mysqld.exe" --defaults- file="C:\Program Files\MySQL Server 5.6\my.ini" --init-file=C:\mysql-init.txt
```

Comment: I think you forgot to add the command. this is just the warning.

Comment: but it's not executing mysql service

Answer (score 0):

To reset the root password if you've forgotten, see the MySQL documentation:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Yes , i followed these procedures but i'm still getting these errors